# MAX(CONVERT(column, TIME(3))) returns different value from mysql client than JPA native query

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, time

MAX(CONVERT(column,  TIME(3))) returns different value from mysql client than JPA native query.
The first is returning (in my example data) the correct value 47:40:00.000 but the JPA native query is returning 23:40:00 and don't know why as it has the native query flag.

Comment: Could you add the '@Entity' and '@Repository' code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was because of conversion from localTime format (equivalent to hibernate TIME) to String. I solved the problem doing the conversion to String on MySQL.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT CAST(MAX(CONVERT(v.start,TIME(3))) AS CHAR) FROM variable v WHERE v.well IN ?1 ", nativeQuery=true);
```